# How do docker-compose network aliases work if there are multiple instances for zero downtime container update?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, docker-network

So I have:

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
  app:
    image: node:latest
```

And my nginx config is:

```
upstream project_app {
  server app:4000;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://project_app;
  }
```

In order to update a container without downtime (rolling updates), I first upscale the `app` service to 2:

```
docker-compose up -d --no-deps --scale app=2 --no-recreate app
```

It will create `project_app_1` along `project_app`.

But at this step, even when the new `project_app_1` container is ready, all the traffic goes to `project_app`, the former container.

To have them both used, I then need to run `docker-compose restart nginx`.

Now, the traffic is router to both `project_app` and `project_app_1`, which is really cool.

I am now ready to kill `project_app` which is outdated now.

My questions are:

- Do I need to restart nginx again after it is killed, to make sure **all** the traffic gets routed to `project_app_1` or is it somewhat automatic?
- The fact that `http://app:4000` works is because of DNS hostname config, right? Where can learn more on this?
- If shutdown discovery works automatically in nginx, ain't there a way to make startup discovery also automatic in order to avoid restarting nginx, which induces a 2 seconds downtime?

Thanks

PS: If you are curious about the whole script I use, I reported it [on the associated github issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1786#issuecomment-579794865).

Comment: Did you try to reload nginx configuration with something like `docker-compose exec nginx nginx -s reload` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally found more info on this.

1. When writing `server app:4000;`, `app` *is* a DNS entry, which resolves to multiple instances.
2. It **is possible** to update those DNS entries **without having to restart nginx**. The detail is here: https://serverfault.com/a/916786/182596

This [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/7b0d23/scaling_in_docker_compose_container_routing/) and [nnginx this article](https://www.nginx.com/blog/dns-service-discovery-nginx-plus/) helped also.

Basically, one has to set on the nginx configuration to

1. use `docker` DNS server `127.0.0.11`
2. Put the proxy in a variable. Here's the conf:

```
resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=10s;

server {
  set $app app:4000;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://$app;
  }
}
```

Once `docker-compose up -d --no-deps --scale app=2 --no-recreate app` is called, it starts routing to both instances.

The issue is that when scaling down, it takes the DNS entry TTL to update that it is not valid anymore, hence, with `10s`, I do have 50% of my traffic being down for `[0-10s]`, which is decent but not perfect.

I'm currently investigating:

- what is a good TTL duration
- if there is a way to manually trigger a DNS entries refresh

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
upstream project_app {
  server app:4000 down;
  server app1:4000 down;
}
```

if app is down it jumps to app1,if app is back up it use it.

Comment: Using `server app:4000;` works so I'm not sure this is helpful. What I'd like to know is what happens behind the scene at the docker network layer.

Comment: its how to exchange containers without need of nxing restart/reload

Comment: This would be pretty much what I am looking for unless the `app1` hadn't to be updated since it increases with the time: `app2`, `app3` etc. Hence I would have to edit the file which implies restarting nginx, wouldn't I?

Comment: well whats problem to rotate app->app1,app1->app,app->app1 and so on.

Comment: Not much, simply I need to restart nginx, which means 1/2 seconds downtime.